# How to find whether a property has compiler-generated backing field?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a scenario where I have to find out whether a specific property represented by a `PropertyInfo` has a compiler generated backing field. I need this information to know if a property is "clearly" computed.

I cannot simply use the `GetSetMethod(true) != null` condition, because C# 6 introduced getter-only properties, which seems to give null, but still I cannot treat them as computed.

For example

```
public class Test {

  public bool A { get; set; } // has a backing field, should give computed = false
  public int B { get; private set; } // has a backing field,should give computed = false
  public int C { get; } // has a backing field,should give computed = false;
  public bool D { get { return B + C > 10; } } // doesn't have backing field, should give computed = true 

  private int _e = 1;
  public int E { get { return _e; } } // has an explicit backing field, so in this sense it should give computed = true

  public Test() {
    B = 3;
    C = 5;
  }
}
```

I'd like to write a small extension method, like this

```
public static bool IsComputed(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
  ...
}
```

**EDIT**

Just to be more clear, before C# 6, I used the simple `GetSetMethod(true) == null` condition to treat a property "computed". But now the getter-only properties (which are sometimes used as an alternative to private getters) are messing it up, because they give `null` as they don't have set method, BUT they shouldn't be treated as computed.

Comment: What about this one `public int E { get { return _myBackingField; } }`?

Comment: In this sense, I would treat it as computed, as it has a user-defined `get` method. I will edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási _all_ properties have a `get` and/or `set` method, but some are generated by the compiler.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'd like to check wether a property has a compiler-generated backing field, I've edited my question, sorry for not being completely clear.

Comment: @DStanley thank you for pointing to a duplicate. It's surprising that still there is no better and more reliable way to do this.

Comment: What's the benefit of knowing that?  If you feel like it's valuable enough to warrant the cost of developing it you can always post a feature request at http://connect.microsoft.com.

Comment: I'm using this information for metadata generation for for example web client-side programming, but I've actually managed to work it around easier than I thought.